# PHP: Why does this comparison evaluates to true?

Tags: php, boolean-logic

The PHP 5.6 code:

```
$nl = '<br/>';
$text = 'hello';
$res = $text? 'true': 'false';
echo "$text evaluates to $res $nl";

$num = 0;
$res = $num? 'true': 'false';
echo "0 evaluates to $res $nl";

$res = $text == 0? 'true': 'false';
echo "$text == $num evaluates to $res $nl";
```

This outputs:

```
hello evaluates to true
0 evaluates to false
hello == 0 evaluates to true
```

I don't understand the last line of output.  How can something `true` be compared to something `false` and have a comparison result of `true`?

**Answer:** The string and the integer are *not* both converted to booleans as I suspected. Instead, the string is converted to a number and then compared to 0.  Because the string does not begin with a numeric character, it evaluates to the number 0 (`var_dump((int)'hello')` will output `int 0`).  So the comparison returns `true` because `"hello" == 0` becomes `0 == 0`